# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str' in robot framework

Tags: python, python-3.x, robotframework

I am getting unsupported operand error. I know numbers are converted o string when we pass to robot but how to fix this?
Python file

```
a=5
b=6
def Addition(a,b):
    s=a+b
    c = 3
    d = 2
    Sub(c,d)
    print(s)
def Sub(c,d):
    e=c-d
    print(e)
Addition(a,b)
```

robot file

```
*** Variables ***
${ra}=    ${a}
${rb}=    ${b}
${rc}=    ${c}
${rd}=    ${d}

*** Test Cases ***
Addition Program
    Addition    a    b
Sub1 Program
    Sub    rc    rd
```

Comment: Maybe casting from str to int?

Comment: Type casting is not working.

Comment: What happens? Same error? On robot or on PC?

Comment: actually if i run python code it works fine but if i run robot code it is giving this error. if i typecast it it is giving "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'rc'
"

Comment: ^ there is your problem then... one of your values is the string `"rc"` rather than a number.  I've never used Robot framework, but looking at the docs https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#using-variables it seems like you should also use the `${rc}` syntax for variables in your test cases, not just in the var definitions at the top

Comment: It looks like the function is trying to cast the letters 'rc' to int() which would indeed fail. I assume 'rc' is a variable, the code seems to treat it as literal string.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with your code. The easier one is how you call your functions; in here for example:

```
Sub    rc    rd
```

, you're not passing the variables *(as you probably think)*, but you're giving strings "rc" and "rd". To pass a var's value you need to use the proper syntax - dollar sign with curly brackets:

```
Sub    ${rc}    ${rd}
```

The other thing is - you're saying the default value of a key word's argument is a string, but that's not entirely so. The framework is going to pass whatever your variable is and by the default it's a string *(as the data type)*. When you write just a number - like:

```
My Keyword    3
```

it's a string - like python's `"3"`.

You can say explicitly state a value should be treated as a numeric with this syntax:

```
My Keyword    ${3.14}
```

Or, you can covert it to int/float beforehand:

```
${ra}=   Convert To Integer   ${ra}
${var}=  Convert To Number    3.14
```

There is another way - so the framework automatically converts to the desired type through python's type hints *(available in RF v>=4.0 I think)*, but that's beyond the scope of the question IMHO - it's applicable only to python calls in the cases, not in the normal RF-only usage.